# unable to generate error and redirect it to a file in perl

Tags: perl, stderr

I am trying to redirect my STDOUT and STDERR to some file. I am successful with that to some extent. But i am not able to understand one thing in the below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (STDOUT,">/var/tmp/outfile") or die "problem : $!";
open (STDERR,">>/var/tmp/outfile") or die "problem : $!";
print "$_\n" foreach (1..10);
sdsdf;  # buggy line inserted wantedly
```

I have inserted the last line assuming that perl would throwout an error and that would be redirected to the file but its not happening . My program does not throughout any error onto the screen nor to the outfile. Please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: @Krishna: The question explains why he added it: "I have inserted the last line assuming that perl would throwout an error and that would be redirected to the file but its not happening ." It's intended to test STDOUT by creating a runtime error (...which would be better done by using `warn` or `die`). Using `strict` would be counter to that purpose, as it would prevent the program from running at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `use strict;`,

```
 sdsdf;
```

is the same as

```
 "sdsdf";
```

That's one of the reasons you always want to use `use strict; use warnings;`. Let's start by adding that.

---

So you want to log all output including compile-time errors to a file. Well, that's not going to happen by redirecting STDERR after your code has been compiled. The best way to do this is from outside your program.

```
script.pl >/var/tmp/outfile 2>&1
```

but it can be done from within your program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
   open(STDOUT, '>', '/var/tmp/outfile')
      or die("Can't redirect STDOUT: $!\n");
   open(STDERR, '>&', \*STDOUT)
      or die("Can't redirect STDERR: $!\n");
}

print "$_\n" foreach (1..10);
sdsdf;  # Syntax error
```

Comment: can you please explain what is happening in this line `open(STDERR, '>&=', \*STDOUT)` i am not getting the `=` and `*STDOUT`

Comment: `*STDOUT` is the name of the variable, and `\*STDOUT` is the file handle known as "standard output", where `print $x;` normally sends its stuff. `>&=` causes STDERR to be opened with the same file descriptor as STDOUT which is actually bad. (But thankfully didn't work because STDERR wasn't closed.) Fixed.

Comment: in the about code i can just go with `open(STDERR, '>&', STDOUT)` right ? not understanding the use of `\*` after `STDOUT` . I tried executing this code with and without `\*` after `STDOUT` both yielded me the same result.

Comment: It might understand that you mean `\*STDOUT` when you say `STDOUT`. I didn't try it.

Answer (score 3):

The sdsdf is not generating any errors (if you `use strict` then you'll see some compile time errors), that's why you are not seeing any messages. Try this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open (STDOUT,">outfile1") or die "problem : $!";
open STDERR, ">&STDOUT";
print "$_\n" foreach (1..10);
die("aaaa");  # buggy line inserted wantedly
```

Also in your code you are opening the same file twice, this might cause some problems. In the above we first redirect the stdout to a file then redirect stderr to stdout.

Comment: sorry but i dont get it ! should not perl throw an error over that as it wont be able to compile the code due the unknown keyword . i know warning switch prints warning message but why not perl interpreter says something about this wrong line?

Comment: Because the bareword `sdsdf` is interpreted as a string and a string on a line does not do anything to generate an output and it is not an error. Similar to having `123123;` on a line.

Comment: You can see a warning for "useless use of constant" if you `use warnings`.

Comment: ok if i enable `use warnings` i get some messages printed on my screen but can you please tell me how to redirect them a file ? is not those warning messages part of STDERR ? If not, how are they different ?